# How to use multiple if/then in JSON schema

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

I have a JSON schema defined as below -

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "prop1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "prop2": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "prop3": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "prop4": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "prop1": {
            "const": "v1"
          },
          "prop2": {
            "const": "v2"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "prop1",
          "prop2",
          "prop3"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "prop1": {
            "const": "v11"
          },
          "prop2": {
            "const": "v22"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": [
          "prop1",
          "prop2",
          "prop4"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
      "required": [
        "prop1",
        "prop2"
      ]
}
```

A few scenarios i would like to validate -

```
{
  "prop1": "aaa"
}
//should say prop2 is required --This works

    {
          "prop1": "aaa",
"prop2": "bbb"
        }
        //should validate to true --This works

{
      "prop1": "v1"
"prop2": "v2"
    }
    //should say prop3 is required --This DOESN'T work

{
      "prop1": "v11"
"prop2": "v22"
    }
    //should say prop4 is required --This DOESN'T work
```

Could someone please help me how to fix the above 2 test cases that doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `anyOf` to a `allOf`, to make sure both conditions are checked.

Due to the way you have written your `if` conditions, only one of them can be true at a time, so for one or the other of them (or both), the `else` clause will be executed, but you haven't provided an `else` clause, so it defaults to `true`, so at least one of the `anyOf` clauses will be true, so `anyOf` is true.

Comment: As a follow up, you may find this article on understanding applicability useful https://json-schema.org/blog/posts/applicability-json-schema-fundamentals-part-1